# How efficient is an old international comfort AC unit

Tags: hvac, air-conditioning

I have an AC unit that’s from 2002. It’s a 3 ton International Comfort M# NAC036AKA4. R22 refrigerant.

I’m concerned it’s using a Freon refrigerant and also probably close to end of life considering it’s been 20 years. I can’t find any information on its SEER ratings.

What is it’s SEER rating and is it worthwhile to replace it?

Comment: Obligatory links to Technology Connections' vids on heat pumps: 1) how it works https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7J52mDjZzto ...... 2) the state of the art https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=MFEHFsO-XSI ...... 3) what's practically available https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=43XKfuptnik

Comment: Imagine a new unit would more efficient than an older one.  Question is will you use it enough to make paying for a new one to pay you back in savings.  Mine is late 80s/early 90s, but have use it maybe 24 hours in the last twenty years

Comment: If it's working let it run. When it fails, replace it. Our old AC unit lasted 27 years running full-time in during the Midwest's annual summer time heat & humidity festival. It was really the furnace's failing that lead us to replace both last summer. There's no need to throw something out just for something shiny and new. Yes, a new unit will be more efficient, but how long will that higher efficiency take to pay you back.

Answer (score 2):

[10 SEER](https://www.answers.com/Q/What_is_the_seer_rating_on_a_comfortmaker_NAC036AKA4)

That it is using Freon is of no real consequence *as long as it doesn't leak*. The problem is that if it leaks then (a) you have released potentially bad stuff into the environment and (b) you need to spend a lot to get the lost refrigerant replaced.

So yes, 20 years is a good time to think about replacement, even if you are not having problems right now. You will save in the long run on energy costs. The payback time will vary a lot depending on how much the unit runs (which depends primarily on the weather, which depends primarily on location), local electricity costs and relative efficiency. Any new unit will be more efficient, but some are much more efficient than others.

Comment: I don't know about the OP's state but in California, R22 refrigerant cannot be legally replaced, AFAIK. I'm currently replacing my 25-year-old HVAC because the condenser unit started immediately tripping the breaker and no one will touch the old unit (except to replace it). Of course, I'm replacing this old unit with a brand new heat-pump so I'll save a lot on my heating bill too.

Answer (score 2):

Your energy savings will start the day you replace it. As said, it is 10 SEER, and other units will be proportionally more efficient.  (A 30 SEER system will cost 1/3 as much to run).

R22 is "not great, not terrible" for the ozone layer but it is a powerful greenhouse gas. And it is no longer made.  If you replaced the A/C *before* it springs a leak, by a qualified person, then a neat thing will happen: that person will "vampire out" the R22 and capture it, sending it up the supply chain for either destruction or reuse.  (This is the only source.)

Heat pumps are worth looking at.  The newest designs can heat *reasonably well* in even Chicago-like winters, and *much more* efficiently on less cold days.  They are head and shoulders above gas during most times, and you can keep your gas as alternative heat. That lets you arbitrage gas vs electric pricing, although it really helps that heating season is relatively low-demand on the electric grid; it is maxed out in the summer with A/C units.

Technology Connections has done a lovely video series on heat pumps:

- how it works https://youtube.com/watch?v=7J52mDjZzto
- the state of the art https://youtube.com/watch?v=MFEHFsO-XSI
- what's practically available https://youtube.com/watch?v=43XKfuptnik
- how to chase cheap electric rates by using your house for energy storage https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0f9GpMWdvWI ... no such thing as time-of-day prices for gas, since gas does store.

Answer (score 1):

It's really hard to know when it will fail. If it was a high quality unit to start with it may last another 10 years. It may take a bit more electricity than more modern units.  Like Manassehkatz said, depends completely on how much run time the unit sees, where you are at, electric rates, etc.   If you only see a few hot months during the year when you run it, it could take a long time to get cost recovery.   And PLEASE, don't worry about Freon, if it's not leaking, you're not harming the environment and if it's working properly, it's not leaking.

My attitude would be: "If it ain't broke, don't fix it"  Just do what the electric companies do:  "run till failure".

Comment: Too bad stuff like that only fails at the worst time possible.  They never fail in the cool months.

Comment: That's directly related to usage, if it's collecting dust it's far less likely to break than if it's running :)